# OpenJDK 17 for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rpm, openjdk

Currently there is no possibility to install java-17-openjdk through `sudo yum install java-17-openjdk` on a CentOS 7 system (`CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`) as it was possible some time ago. When I now search for other openjdk versions, I can find the packages

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-11-openjdk
java-latest-openjdk (OpenJDK 18)
```

Also looking at https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-17-openjdk I cannot find an entry for CentOS 7.

I need OpenJDK 17. Is there some possibility to install it through a rpm package or any other alternative?

Comment: You may always download the JDK, unpack it to a certain folder, and update all needed Environment-Variables to make it work. Does it have to be installed via a package?

Comment: I don't know which environment variables has to be changed and which values they need.

Answer (score 2):

You might simply build this yourself. If it worked before, chances are the build for Fedora works. You will need a Fedora 34+ host to cross-build this.

```bsh
# Don't build as root. Only need root privileges to install `fedpkg`,
sudo dnf install -y fedpkg

# Now get the package description
git clone https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/java-17-openjdk
# Use fedpkg to kick off a mock build
cd java-17-openjdk
fedpkg mockbuild --root centos-7-x86_64
```

This will take a while¹; and in the end, you should be getting a line that tells you where the RPMs you've just built were put.

---

¹ `mock` sets up a chroot, in which it installs a CentOS 7 base system, then EPEL, which you'll almost certainly will need, I think, then the tools necessary to build any RPM, then the build-time dependencies of the java-17-openjdk package. Then it will  download all the necessary source code, hand off to `rpm-build` to do the build, which includes applying all patches, then compiling OpenJDK, then,  running the OpenJDK installation, collecting the installed files, compressing them into valid RPMs.

Comment: note: on RHEL7 use yum instead of dnf to install fedpkg which seems to work, then the fedpkg run fails

Comment: @splaisan that's why I said you need Fedora >= 34; RHEL 7 just lacks too much.

Comment: My bad, i was so in it i did not read you well. I will have to reinstall that server one day.....